# Array of a Structure Inside a Structure, C++ Code

Tags: c++, structure

I'm working on a preparing some code for what will ultimately be a MUD; this is my first 'big' project and I am gradually chiseling out the errors; however, some problems are now hindering my project and I just can't seem to break them. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int test_var;
#define K    125
#define TEST 50

struct item {
int quantity;
//Some More Stuff Will Be Inside Later//
};

struct inventory {
  struct item[K];  //Error 1 - "expected unqualified-id before '[' token"
} test;

int main()
{
cout << "Number?" << endl;
cin >> test_var;
test.item[TEST].quantity = test_var;  //Error 2 - "'struct inventory' has no member named 'item'"
cout << test.item[TEST].quantity << endl;  //Error 3 - "'struct inventory' has no member named 'item'"
cout << test.item[TEST].quantity;  //Error 4 - "'struct inventory' has no member named 'item'"
return 0;
}
```

I have to apologize as this code is a bit sloppy, but this represents two things tasks that I'm trying to accomplish. Number 1, I need some way of having an array of structure 'items' inside the structure 'inventory'. Number 2, I need to insure that I can access the individual elements inside the structures; the actual code involves a couple more structures inside structures and it is vital that I can access the individual, non-structure elements (ints, bools, doubles, strings). If anyone can offer many any advice on these issues, I would be grateful. Thank you

Comment: The first error in the struct item[k] is that you havent given the item a name. try this: struct item name[k]

Answer (score 3):

```
struct item[K];
```

You are missing the identifier/name of the object for the struct. Notice that `item` itself is a struct. So, try

```
struct item obj[K];  // struct key word is unnecessary
```